# Custom product choices with shopping cart rules

Tags: cart, rules

I'm running Magento 1.8 Community edition.
I have a product with one custom choice.

So I add the choices and give them SKU
NO INSTALLATION 
with SKU:TILLV000
INSTALLATION 
with SKU: TILLV001
SUPER INSTALLATION
with SKU: TILLV002

Now IF you choose any of the custom choices with SKU: TILLV001 OR TILLV002. Rhen I would like to enable free shopping.

I added that as a shopping cart rule

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ANY  of these conditions true: 
SKU  is  TILLV001, TILLV002

It doesnt apply? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento does not take into account custom options when calculate shopping cart rules unless you have an extension for this.

We do the following trick: rewrite class Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product  and add 2 new custom attributes 
'Custom Options SKU'  and 'Custom Options Values'

Then get options to validate as 
`$options = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product);`

and SKU as `$object->getSku()` where $object is the quote item.

Comment: The file path is app\code\core\Mage\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product.php for the original magento file, and I think you need to create a new local module to rewrite it.

Comment: Not sure I follow after you add the attribute to `_addSpecialAttributes()` - If I add a new attribute to the select element using: `$attributes['quote_item_myattribute']`, do I simply need to set this to `$product` in the `validate()` method? Ie: `$product->setQuoteItemMyattribute($object->getMyattribute())`?